# Excel Pivot Chart - Lables of Grouped Values in Chart

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-charts, pivot-chart, excel-pivot

I created a Pivot Table of countries with their avg wine tastings points from a wine tatings dataset, and then grouped them by geographical region, and made a Pivot Chart from that.

[image: Pivot Table]

**The problem** is that the lables of the grouped values (aka the geographical regions) are verical while the original values (countries) are horizontal.. I want them both horizontal to take less space vertically..

[image: Pivot Chart]

I tried messing with the design options of the lables, but it seems to apply only on the original values (countries), since it's already set to horizontal and changing to anything else there only affects the countries...

Any ideas? Preferably without VBA since I don't know how to use it.. If you do have a VBA solution then please explain where should I paste the code.

Also - do you have ideas to better distinct the geographical regions? I want this chart to show the rankings of the geographical regions, as well as the rankings of countries in each geographical region.

Thank you very much!